# Corrigir dados do banco do SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero corrigir um campo da tabela, pois estou com valores assim: `123456789` e quero alterar para `1234567.89`

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado da coluna?

Comment: Você precisa que sua coluna seja do tipo `decimal(X,X)` e depois aplicar o update

Comment: e o valor de recibos, eu tinha salvado os valores assim 1.850,00. mas nao estava somando corretamente. ai corrigi na tabela os valor removendo o ponto e a virgula. agora quero adicionar o ponto dos centavos

Comment: eu coloquei ela como decimal mas ficou `decimal(30,0)` esta correto?

Comment: Ater de remover o ponto e virgula estava 1.850,00 agora apos ter removido os pontos e virgulas o valor ficou 185000. o que estou precisando e colocar o ponto novamente para separa os centavo 1850.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para colocar as casas decimais, é só você multiplicar o valor por 0.01.
123456789 * 0.01 = 1234567.89

update tabela set coldecimal = coldecimal * 0.01

Mas antes, altere o tipo da coluna.

Comment: Inteligente :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Execute o comando:

```
ALTER TABLE tabela MODIFY coluna DECIMAL(10, 2);
```

Comment: ao aplicar esse comando um valor que tinha que era 3000 ficou 3000.00 eu gostaria que ficasse 30.00

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com o seguinte codigo

`update cad_recibo SET valor_recibo = REPLACE(valor_recibo, '00.00', '.00');`

so que se tiver algum valor com centavos nao altera. ai eu queria alguma forma de fazer os valores com centavos tambem